# PermitListen option in sshd_config does not work

Tags: ssh, openssh, sshd

I'm trying to put the following into my `sshd_config` file:

```
Match User apricot
        PermitListen 53000
```

Restarting OpenSSH server via the `service sshd restart` command fails. The command `journalctl -xe` reveals the following relevant errors:

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config: line 133: Bad configuration option: PermitListen
/etc/ssh/sshd_config line 133: Directive 'PermitListen' is not allowed within a Match block
```

This is weird because when I look at the documentation via `man sshd_config`, it tells me that I should be able to use `PermitListen` under a `Match` block. [man7](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sshd_config.5.html) says the same thing.

I'm using version "OpenSSH_8.3p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018" which I built from source after OpenSSH_7.6p1 was giving me the same error.

OS version: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you _sure_ you're using the built-from-source version? That config item was added in 7.8, so it should work in 8.3, but not in 7.6.

Comment: Could you post the config file? This command will output the lines that are not commented or empty: `egrep -v '^$|^#' /etc/ssh/sshd_config`. Check the location of the `sshd_config`, it might be somewhere else in your system.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 You are right, I wasn't running the built-from-source version. The init.d script was trying to launch `/usr/sbin/sshd` which was the 7.6 binary. After I symlinked `/usr/sbin/sshd` to point to the built-from-source binary, things started working. Thanks!